# remove spot emission reflection cycles

Tags: modeling, lighting

Blend File: [image]

I have looked at many other questions and cant find the solution for my issue. I have placed a spot light inside the bottle and figured out how to hide the spot light, but the light reflects off the inside objects and can be seen. You can check out my blend file to see what my issue looks like, but how can I keep the light and hid the ball and all the reflections without losing the glow to light the inside. I've tried all the ray visibility check boxes to the light, and nothing will make that yellow oval go away without losing the glow.

[image]
[image]